# LinearLayout minHeight not working with weigth="1"

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I tried all afternoon to get the `minHeight` attribute to work.

What I want is the `linearMe` layout to:

- Stretch from the bottom of the screen to the bottom of the ListView when the ListView has just a few elements.
- I need to be able to fill the linearMe layout with a picture for example.

As the ListView gets bigger I want the `linearMe` layout to:

- Have a fixed height (while being at the bottom of the screen) and the ListView to allow scrolling.

My problem is that the the `linearMe` layout is smaller and smaller as there is more elements in the ListView. And when there is enough element for the listView to fill the screen, the `linearMe` layout is just gone. It looks like the `minHeight` is useless in this case.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearMe"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#FF0000"
    android:minHeight="200dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image][image]

I hope you can help me out ! :)

Comment: I had solve same problem, see my answer :- [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42832856/minheight-not-working-with-weight-1-in-linearlayout/43199823#43199823](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42832856/minheight-not-working-with-weight-1-in-linearlayout/43199823#43199823)

Comment: Switch to `ConstraintLayout` sooner than later!

Answer (score 0):

Add         `android:layout_weight="1"` to the ListView as well.
Change them both (list & linearMe)        `android:layout_height` attribute to `"match_parent"`
Remove `minHeight.

That way each View will take half of the screen.`

Comment: That's not what I want ... I want to take advantage of all the available space is there is only one item in the ListView for example.

Comment: So why not set maxHieght to the ListView? ANyway best to do such thing dynamically via code and not xml

Comment: Are you sure maxHeight exists ? I don't think so. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try your spacer layout using "View" instead of "LinearLayout". The ViewGroup classes sometimes handle layouts slightly differently.

Comment: How do I add content to it then ?

Comment: Keep LinearLayout as your root layout, but use View for the spacer view. (given your example code above).

Comment: Let say i want to put a picture in the `linearMe` layout. How is it possible with your solution ?

Comment: It's not. Given your sample code, it looked like you were just trying to set a background color on the bottom portion of the screen.

Comment: Ok sorry about that. I will clarify my question. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use `ConstraintLayout` as the parent container, the following xml should serve your purpose:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/linearMe"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:listitem="@android:layout/list_content" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearMe"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="#FF0000"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/list"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_min="200dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

What I've done is that I've defined constraints to chain both `list` and `linearMe` with each other. `app:layout_constraintHeight_min="200dp"` will ensure minimum height of 200dp for `linearMe`. `app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"` makes sure that when `list` has more items, it doesn't hide behind `linearMe`.

I couldn't test it with some data to fill the `ListView`. You can just try it out and post your feedback here.