# minHeight not working with weight=“1” in Linearlayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I want a View that can have a minimum height or wrap_content if screen size is small and if screen size is large then occupy the rest of the space. This view is middle child of its parent.

Currently, I am using weight with LinearLayout. It's working fine with large screen but on a small screen its not showing the view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/speaker_detail_background"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_7dp"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_7dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/down_arrow_image_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/down_arrow_icon" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/lytSpeakerDetails"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/down_arrow_image_view"
        android:minHeight="200dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/title_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
                android:visibility="visible"
                >

                <com.harman.jblconnectplus.ui.customviews.CustomFontTextView
                    android:id="@+id/speaker_name_title_textview"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/edit_name"
                    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/padding_5dp"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:maxLength="16"
                    android:text="@string/speaker_name"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/textSize_18sp"
                    app:font="@string/font_name_opensans_semi"
                    />

                <com.harman.jblconnectplus.ui.customviews.CustomFontTextView
                    android:id="@+id/setting_text_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/speaker_name_title_textview"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:text="@string/setting"
                    android:visibility="invisible"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    app:font="@string/font_name_opensans_semi"
                    />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/lytSeekBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_below="@id/title_bar"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/brightness_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/brightness_margin"
                android:visibility="visible">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/darker"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    />
                <SeekBar
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/seekBar"
                    android:thumb="@drawable/knob"
                    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_progressbar"
                    android:indeterminate="false"
                    android:splitTrack="false"
                    android:maxHeight="3dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:progress="0"
                    android:secondaryProgress="0"
                    android:max="255"

                    />
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/brighter"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_details_layout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/round_border_white_bg"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_20dp"
         >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_5dp"
            android:gravity="bottom">

            <include layout="@layout/speaker_detail_firmware_layout" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
            android:background="@color/divider_view" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <include layout="@layout/speaker_detail_voice_layout" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i had solve this problem. set weight "1" of layout in XML File(in my
>   case XML is same as Given above), it will work in case of if Screen
>   size is large and also check grammatically  if size of view is less
>   than a minimum size then set height of view grammatically. sample
>   code:-

Set ViewTreeObserver to View:-

```
lytSpeakerDetails = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.lytSpeakerDetails);
            ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = lytSpeakerDetails.getViewTreeObserver();
            viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(globalLayoutListener);
```

and in Listener's callback check if layout height is less than minimum then set height to minimum:-

```
ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener globalLayoutListener = new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            if (!isAdded())
                return;
            lytSpeakerDetails.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

            int height = lytSpeakerDetails.getMeasuredHeight();

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams imgViewParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) lytSpeakerDetails.getLayoutParams();

           /*  imgViewParams.setMargins(0, (int) ( x * 1.5f) + (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.card_shadow_y), 0, (int) x  );
            lytSpeakerDetails.setLayoutParams(imgViewParams);*/

            if(height < (int)getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.brightness_minimum_height)) {

                LinearLayout.LayoutParams rel_btn = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.brightness_minimum_height));

                lytSpeakerDetails.setLayoutParams(rel_btn);
            }

        }
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `View` is being constrained. `minHeight` is not guaranteed to be honored if the `View` is constrained. See the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:minHeight).

> android:minHeight
>
> Defines the minimum height of the view. It is not guaranteed the view will be able to achieve this minimum height (for example, if its parent layout constrains it with less available height).

Maybe a `ScrollView` is something that you can use since it gives you virtually unlimited space. The question is what you want to happen when space becomes an issue and everything just can't fit.